# Let $f(x)= \frac{x^4-\lambda x^3-3x^2+3\lambda x}{x-\lambda}$ Condition for $\lambda$ according to question?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $f(x)= \frac{x^4-\lambda x^3-3x^2+3\lambda x}{x-\lambda}$, If range of $f(x)$ is the set of entire real numbers then the true set in which $\lambda$ lies is?

The options are: (a) $[-2,2]$ (b) $[0,4]$ (c) $(1,3)$

The answer is $[-2,2]$

What I did was, factorize it out and then what I got was, $f(x)= \frac{(x^3-3x)(x-\lambda)}{(x-\lambda)}$

I can see that the local maximum and local minimum values of the polynomial $x^3-3x$ is $2,-2$ respectively, but what do I do to find the value of $\lambda$?

Comment: The image of $x^3 - 3x$ over the reals is the entire real line. Those maxima and minima are only local.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yeah I was talking about the local minima and maxima there. I'll edit it in

Comment: That still leaves me puzzles about the answer to your question. The image of $f$ over the reals will be the whole real line excluding $f(\lambda)$, since $f$ is not defined at $\lambda$. The question doesn't seem to make any sense unless the domain of $f$ is restricted.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yes that's what I thought at first but I'm not sure what I'm missing here....

Comment: the $x^3 - 3x$ represents values between $-2,2$ three times, also $2$ and $-2$ twice. For any number bigger than $2$ there is just one $x$ value that works, which is also bigger than $2.$  If $\lambda > 2$ and matches up with the target number, the target number is not represented by the original fraction.

Comment: @WillJagy Could you show one example where this occurs here? Like for example if $\lambda = 4$, then you mean that 52 won't be represented by the original function. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $g(x) =x^3 - 3x$ we have $g(4) = 52$  If your $\lambda = 4$ there is no longer a way to represent $52$ by the original fraction, which is undefined at $4.$ The graph would have one of those little open circles at $(4,52)$

In brief, for target numbers larger than $2,$  there is just one $x$ value that works, and this $x$ value is also bigger than two.

Comment: Yes this is the same thing that I replied to in your comment, thanks for clarifying and this helped a lot.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Thank you for answering my question as well.